# Using node summary on custom view

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-7

I'm building a custom view ona drupal site and i added all the fields i wanted, but i can't seem to find out how to add the summary that i created for the node. Anyone can help?

I've added Body, put it doesn't include the summary.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the "Summary" stored? Is it a separate CCK field?

Comment: When adding a new content you can press 'show summary' on the body field. It seems, as jhedstrom said, Drupal treats this as the teaser.

Answer (score 22):

Ahah - just ran into the same problem - confused me for a moment too.

Go to the View in question, click the `+` icon to add a field, and select `Fields: body`. Then when the configuration options for that comes up, go to the very bottom and you'll see a drop down labelled `Formatter` - select `Summary or trimmed`. I think this gives you the summary if it exists, if not it will trim it for you.

Answer (score 2):

While the node form refers to this as the 'Summary', elsewhere, such as in the Views UI, it is typically called the 'teaser'. You should be able to find this field listed along with other node fields when editing your view.

Comment: All right, it seems it's called teaser, after all. Still can't see where on the view editing i can add it to the view, instead of the body.